# Hola, estoy implementando el método de mezcla directa en un programa en c, pero aun tengo ciertos problemas

Tags: c, ordenamiento

### MEZCLA DIRECTA (METODO DE ORDENAMIENTO

---

Bueno mis dudas son en las funciones de:

1. Mezclas directa
2. particiona
3. fusiona

---

Las líneas que no se que poner son:

> scanf ("%d", &R1);

---

Se que tengo muchas fallas sobre mi código, soy nuevo en programación y estoy estudiando métodos de ordenamiento, en este caso es de Mezclas directa

---

La partes en la que me provoca confusión las comente en el código, ahora solo dejos las tres funciones que ocupo

```
    void mezcla_directa (int F[T], int F1[T], int F2[T], int N) {

        int PART;
        PART = 1;
        while (PART < ((N+1)%2)) {
            particiona (F, F1, F2, PART, N);
            fusiona (F, F1, F2, PART);
            PART = PART * 2;
        }
        ver (F, N);
    }

    void particiona (int F[T], int F1[T], int F2[T], int PART, int N) {

        int K, L, R = 1;
        while (F[T] != NULL) {
            K = 1;
            while ((K < PART) && (R <= N)) {
                scanf ("%d", &R); /*No estoy seguro que es lo que debería de hacer en esta parte*/
                printf ("\n%d en %d", R, F1);
                K++;
            }
            L = 0;
            while ((L < PART) && (R <= N)) {
                scanf ("%d", &R); /*No estoy seguro que es lo que debería de hacer en esta parte*/
                printf ("\n%d en %d", R, F2);
                L++;
            }
        }
    }

    void fusiona (int F[T], int F1[T], int F2[T], int PART) {

        int R1, R2, K, L;
        bool B1, B2;
        B1 = true; B2 = true;
        if (F1[T] != NULL) {
            scanf ("%d", &R1);
            B1 = false;
        }
        if (F2[T] != NULL) {
            scanf ("%d", &R2);
            B2 = false;
        }
        while ((F1[T] != NULL) || (B1 == false) && (F2 != NULL) || (B2 == false)) {
            K = 0; L = 0;
            while ((K < PART) && (B1 == false) && (L < PART) && (B2 == false)) {
                if (R1 <= R2) {
                    printf ("\n%d en %d", R1, F);
                    B1 = true; K++;
                    if (F1[T] != NULL) {
                        scanf ("%d", &R1);/*No estoy seguro que es lo que debería de hacer en esta parte*/
                        B1 = false;
                    }   
                } else {
                    printf ("\n %d en %d", R2, F);
                    B2 = true; L++;
                    if (F2[T] != NULL) {
                        scanf ("%d", & R2); /*No estoy seguro que es lo que debería de hacer en esta parte*/
                        B2 = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: De igual forma siento si se ve mal mi pregunta, también estoy empezando a usar stack over flow

Comment: venis bien.. lee [ask] y de paso, cual es el problema particular?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido! Creo que lo único que te hace falta es ser específico con los problemas que encuentras, para que los demás puedan ayudarte. ¿Qué errores obtienes?¿Qué valores/comportamiento obtienes y cómo eso difiere de lo que necesitas (descrito de una manera puntual y técnica)?

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones de acerca de como formular mejor mi pregunta, acabo de comentar en las parte que no estoy seguro de lo que debería de hacer.